# My Hard disk drive is different from what the sticker said it would be (Western digital), is av HDD bad?

Tags: hard-drive

Long story short I bought an HDD based on the sticker on it I thought it was this:

- **WD Blue 1TB WD10EZEX**

But it turned out it was this:

- **Western Digital AV-GP 1TB WD10EURX**

So now I tried to learn about these AV drives and I was wondering if it was different in other than the ROM (5400 vs 7200) and would you suggest getting replacement if I could or am I trading speed for reliability here?

Comment: They're both 7200rpm but the AV one uses the *IntelliPower algorithm, which varies the rotational speed between 5400RPM and 7200RPM* (WD proprietary). Supposedly it saves power but for almost all usage scenarios it will be exactly the same. Don't be misguided by marketing.

Comment: regardless of the rpm the write speed of the AV HDD is about 110MB/sec while the other is 150MB/sec

Comment: And that is utterly irrelevant in **almost all usage scenarios**.

Comment: I am not arguing with you because I really don't know much about HDDs but I would appreciate it if you explained why

Comment: If I intended to explain why I would be answering, not commenting ;) Enough to say the difference is **less than 2 secs for a 1GB file** (lab conditions, theoretical; the real world is way more kinky). If that matters to you go ahead an change it!

Comment: @MichaelBay a 25% difference is quite significant, especially if it applies to random access too.

Comment: If the drive had a sticker which indicated one thing, and the drive indicates something else, then somebody removed the sticker and placed it on the hdd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a crap shot with either drive - These drives date back to just after the Bangkok floods which devastated hard drive production and reliability for a fair time afterwards.

Theoretically you are trading speed for reliability (the former came with a 2 year warranty, the latter with a 3), but I would not put any stock in in either of these drives.   You are probably giving up more in terms of speed then you are receiving in reliability.

Unless you are using it as a media storage drive, its not the right tool for the job - but it will work.

Comment: I concur. I haven't mentioned it before because there's no "real world" difference between them.

Comment: Well the sticker said it was produced in 2016 but the sticker lied before, is there something else other than the reduced speed that I could notice

Comment: If you thought you were buying a 2016 hd but it is actually a 2012 he you are being screwed. AS A very rough rule of thumb, the risk of disk failure increased by 20% per annum.  Also, the drive would probably be in manufacturers warranty if produced in 2016, but not 2012.  Likewise it will be more reliable because of the stability of the factories.  I'd suggest plugging the drive in and getting the SMART info from it - including model and serial no, then look to Western Digitals site for its real age and warranty status.

Comment: Well smart says everything is ok and I managed to get the serial number from western digital data life guard but the page doesn't provide a manufacturing date or a warranty because it is listed as an OEM product

Comment: There is an option to register the hard disk, I hope that means it wasn't used before.

Comment: One detail missing is where the HDD was purchased. Did you purchase from WD direct? Or from eBay or similar?

Comment: @AhmadHani - If it is an OEM product then you purchased a used product (or a re-certified product)

Comment: @CharlieRB something similar to eBay

Comment: Where you purchased it is an important detail. I would suggest you contact the place you purchased it and ask them why it was relabeled.

Comment: I returned the HDD but now I need to figure out how to know the true production date on oem devices because every store in Egypt where I live sells only oem drives

Comment: Why not call up Ingram Micro Egypt and ask them for a reputable reseller in your area. If still unconvinced, see if you can cross check with them once the drive has been purchased. (Ingram Micro is a reputable worldwide computer parts distributor - I'm assuming they will do Seagate or we drives in your region)

Comment: If you are after greater reliability, and can pay more, consider getting a 4tb or larger drive, or an SSD. There is less reliability risk with these drives.